# jQuery id name is being added to the document while using after()

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 4 Alpha.

I want to move my right1 column after left1 when the window gets smaller, but when I refresh the page in a small screen, #left1 text is being added to the screen, like below.

I couldn't understand why such thing happens.

[image: ]]

Here's my current page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="nav.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="feed.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2" id="left1">
                <div class="col-md-12">PROFILE</div>
                <div class="col-md-12" id="menu">MENU</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-7">NEWS</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3" id="right1">RIGHT PART</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="holder.js"></script>
    <script src="tether.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            if($(window).width() < 768){
                $("#right1").after("#left1");
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I want to move my right1 column after left1*

I guess you want to do this:

```js
$("#right1").after($("#left1"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2" id="left1">LEFT PART
  <div class="col-md-12">PROFILE</div>
  <div class="col-md-12" id="menu">MENU</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-7">NEWS</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3" id="right1">RIGHT PART</div>
```

Comment: No, I don't. Normally (desktop) right part is on the right, I want to move it to left part when the screen gets smaller. But #left1 text is being added automatically, I couldn't figure out where it comes from.

Comment: @salep this is really interesting as it should work but it is appending it as a text. But instead of passing an id you can pass an object, see the edits.

Comment: Your solution works until I refresh the page, it's really interesting. It should work, but it doesn't. I think there's a conflict, I'am looking into my scripts more carefully right now.